# download file: ReadTimeout VB net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, stream, memorystream

I want to download file from the path with VB net moves using MemoryStream but I have this exception:

```
ReadTimeout = 'Stream.ReadTimeout' a levé une exception de type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

[image]

Comment: Please try to paste your code directly onto your question post and avoid using images.

Comment: Dim strPathFichier As String = Server.MapPath(documentADownload.CheminFichier)

Dim Stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strPathFichier))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like this in vb net

`Dim file As New FileStream(fielname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Stream.WriteTo(file)
        file.Close()
        Stream.Close()`